# I dont want to reload all the php page after dropbox selection

Tags: php

I have a php page to present in a table characteristics after you select a name in a dropbox. But when you make a selection all the page is reloaded and dublicate the upper div that I have.

```html
<?php include("datalogin.php");  ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Ιατρείο Πόνου</title>


<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

<!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>

<link href="template.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.4.2"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/interface.js"></script>

<script>
function showDetails(id)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("details").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","patients.php?q="+id,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Athens");

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkWindowSize() {  
  
    if ( $(window).height() > 800 ) {  
 document.getElementById('sidebar').class="large");
        $('sidebar').addClass('large');  
    }  
    else {  
        $('body').removeClass('large');  
    }  
  
  }  
  
$(window).resize(checkWindowSize);  
</script>





<!--[if lt IE 7]>
 <style type="text/css">
 div, img { behavior: url(iepngfix.htc) }
 </style>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body onload="checkWindowSize();">

<div>
<div id="sidebar">

  <p align="center" style="font-size:21px">Ιατρείο Πόνου<br/>Σελίδα Διαχείρισης</p>
        <?php if( (session_is_registered("username")) ) {?>
        <p align="center" style="font-size:19px;">Καλως ήλθες <b><span class="yellow"><?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?></span></b>. <br/> <a href="logout.php" class="yellow">Αποσύνδεση</a></p>
        <?php } ?>
        <ul id="main-nav">
        <li><a href="patients.php" class="current">Ασθενείς</a> </li>
        <li><a href="success.php">Επιτυχόντες</a> </li>
   <li><a href="gallery.php">Σχέδια</a> </li>
      <li><a href="settings.php">Ρυθμίσεις Λογαριασμού</a></li>
  </li>
  </ul>
  
  <div id="top_menu">
    <ul id="links" class="clear">
 <li><a href="../sxoli.php" title="Η ΣΧΟΛΗ ΜΑΣ" class="yellow" target="_blank">Η ΣΧΟΛΗ ΜΑΣ</a></li>
 <li><a href="../arxitektoniki-tei.php" title="ΑΡΧΙΤΕΚΤΟΝΙΚΗ-ΤΕΙ" class="red1" target="_blank">ΑΡΧΙΤΕΚΤΟΝΙΚΗ-ΤΕΙ</a></li>
 <li><a href="../kalwn_texnwn.php" title="ΚΑΛΩΝ ΤΕΧΝΩΝ" class="red2" target="_blank">ΚΑΛΩΝ ΤΕΧΝΩΝ</a></li>
 <li><a href="../portfolio.php" title="PORTFOLIO" class="red3" target="_blank">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
    <li><a href="../gallery" title="ΣΧΕΔΙΑ" class="yellow" target="_blank">ΣΧΕΔΙΑ</a></li>
    <li><a href="../sxoles-me-sxedio.php" title=" ΣΧΟΛΕΣ ΜΕ ΣΧΕΔΙΟ" class="yellow" target="_blank">ΣΧΟΛΕΣ ΜΕ ΣΧΕΔΙΟ</a></li>
    <li><a href="../anakoinwseis.php" title="ΑΝΑΚΟΙΝΩΣΕΙΣ" class="light_brown" target="_blank">ΑΝΑΚΟΙΝΩΣΕΙΣ</a></li>
    <li><a href="../epityxontes.php" title="ΕΠΙΤΥΧΟΝΤΕΣ" class="light_brown" target="_blank">ΕΠΙΤΥΧΟΝΤΕΣ</a></li>
    <li><a href="../faq.php" title="FAQ" class="yellow" target="_blank">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="../contact.php" title="ΕΠΙΚΟΙΝΩΝΙΑ" class="grey" target="_blank">ΕΠΙΚΟΙΝΩΝΙΑ</a></li>
 </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="main-content">

<div class="dock" id="dock">
  <div class="dock-container">
  <a class="dock-item" href="patients.php"><img src="images/announcement.png" alt="Ανακοινώσεις" /><span>Ανακοινώσεις</span></a> 
  <a class="dock-item" href="success.php"><img src="images/success.png" alt="Επιτυχόντες" /><span>Επιτυχόντες</span></a> 
  <a class="dock-item" href="gallery.php"><img src="images/gallery.png" alt="Σχέδια" /><span>Σχέδια</span></a> 
  <a class="dock-item" href="settings.php"><img src="images/settings.png" alt="Ρυθμίσεις Λογαριασμού" /><span>Ρυθμίσεις Λογαριασμού</span></a>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 
 $(document).ready(
  function()
  {
   $('#dock').Fisheye(
    {
     maxWidth: 64,
     items: 'a',
     itemsText: 'span',
     container: '.dock-container',
     itemWidth: 50,
     proximity: 90,
     halign : 'center'
    }
   )
  }
 );

</script>


 

         <h2>Ασθενείς</h2>
   <div align="right"><a href="#"><table><tr><td align="center"><img src="images/new.png" alt="Νέα Ανακοίνωση"/></td></tr><tr><td>Νέος Ασθενής</td></tr></table></a></div>
   <p></p>

  
  
  
  
  
        


 <div align="center" id='details'>Επιλέξτε Ασθενή:
<select name="users" onchange="showDetails(this.value)">
  <option value="result">Select</option>
  <?php

 $id=$_GET['q'];
 echo $result = mysql_query("SELECT pa_id, pa_surname, pa_name FROM patient ORDER BY pa_surname");

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
 {
    echo "<option value='".$row["pa_id"]. "'";
  if($row["pa_id"]==$id) { echo " selected";}
  echo ">".$row["pa_surname"]." ".$row["pa_name"]."</option>";
 }?>
</select>
</div>










<?php

$details_query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM patient WHERE pa_id='".$id."'");

while ($details = mysql_fetch_array($details_query))
{ ?>
<p></p>
<div align="center">
<table width="100%" class="box-table-a">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="5"><div align="center">Στοιχεία Ασθενή</div></th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Όνομα :</td>
    <td><?php echo $details['pa_name'];?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Επίθετο :</td>
    <td><?php echo $details['pa_surname'];?></td>
     </tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td>Φύλλο :</td>
    <td>
 <?php 
 $sex_query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sex WHERE sex_id='".$details['sex_id']."'");
 $sex1 = mysql_fetch_array($sex_query);
 echo $sex1['sex_name'];?></td>
  </tr>
   
   
   
   
   <tr>
    <td>Ημερ/νία Γέννησης :</td>
    <td>
 
  
 <?php 
$phpdate = strtotime( $details['pa_birth'] );
$mysqldate = date( 'd-m-Y', $phpdate );
echo $mysqldate;
echo "  ";
$bday = new DateTime($details['pa_birth']);
// $today = new DateTime('00:00:00'); - use this for the current date
$today = new DateTime(); // for testing purposes

$diff = $today->diff($bday);
printf('( %d Ετών )', $diff->y);



?>
 
 
  
 </td>
   </tr>
    



 
  <tr>
    <td >Διεύθυνση κατοικίας :</td>
    <td><?php echo $details['pa_address'];?></td>
 
 
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Περιοχή :</td>
    <td><?php echo $details['pa_area'];?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Πόλη :</td>
    <td><?php echo $details['pa_city'];?></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Τ.Κ. :</td>
    <td><?php echo $details['pa_tk'];?></td>
  </tr> 
   
   <tr>
    <td>Τηλέφωνο :</td>
    <td><?php echo $details['pa_tel'];?></td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>Κινητό :</td>
    <td><?php echo $details['pa_tel2'];?></td>
  </tr> 
 <tr>
    <td>E mail :</td>
    <td><?php echo $details['pa_mail'];?></td>
  </tr>
    
     <tr>
    <td>Ταμείο :</td>
    <td>
 <?php 
 $asfalisi_query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM asfalisi WHERE asfalisi_id='".$details['asfalisi_id']."'");
 $asfalisi1 = mysql_fetch_array($asfalisi_query);
 echo $asfalisi1['asfalisi_name'];?></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Παραπέμπων Ιατρός:</td>
    <td><?php echo $details['doctor_come'];?></td>
  </tr>
  
 <tr>
    <td>Ιστορικό :</td>
    <td><?php echo $details['pa_history'];?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Φάρμακα που έπερνε :</td>
    <td><?php echo $details['pa_farmaka'];?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Σχόλια :</td>
    <td><?php echo $details['pa_com'];?></td>
  </tr>
 
 
 
 
 
 <tr>
    <td>Πάθηση :</td>
    <td>
 <?php 
 
 $pathisi1= mysql_query("SELECT path_id FROM meeting WHERE pa_id= 1 ORDER BY path_id DESC LIMIT 1");
 $pathisi2 = mysql_fetch_array($pathisi1);
 
 
 
 
 $pathisi_query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pathiseis WHERE path_id='".$pathisi2['path_id']."'");
 $pathisi = mysql_fetch_array($pathisi_query);
 echo $pathisi['path_name'];?></td>
  </tr>
    
  <tr>
    <td>Θεραπεία :</td>
    <td>
 <?php 
 
 $therapy1= mysql_query("SELECT ther_id FROM meeting WHERE pa_id= 1 ORDER BY ther_id DESC LIMIT 1");
 $therapy2 = mysql_fetch_array($therapy1);

 $therapy_query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM therapy WHERE ther_id='".$therapy2['ther_id']."'");
 $therapy = mysql_fetch_array($therapy_query);
 echo $therapy['ther_name'];?></td>
  </tr>
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
  
    
</table>
<p></p>


<table  width="100%" class="box-table-a">
    
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2"><div align="center">Εξετάσεις</div></th>
  </tr>
  
  
<?php
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM document WHERE pa_id='".$id."'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {


 ?>

  <tr>

<td><?php echo "<li><a href='eggrafa/".$id."/".$row['document_link']."' target='blank'>".$row['document_title']."</a></li> ";?></td> 

 <?php } ?>
   </tr>
 

</table>

<p></p>

<table  width="100%" class="box-table-a">
    
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2"><div align="center">Επισκέψεις</div></th>
  </tr>
  
  
<?php
   $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM meeting WHERE pa_id='".$id."' ORDER BY meet_id ASC ");
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {


 ?>

  <tr>

<td colspan="2"><?php echo  "<li><a href='meeting.php?id=".$row2['meet_id']."' class='fancybox'>";$phpdate = strtotime( $row2['meet_date'] );
$mysqldate = date( 'd-m-Y', $phpdate );
echo $mysqldate;"</a></li> ";?></td> 

 <?php } ?>
   </tr>
 
<tr>
    <th colspan="2"><div align="center">Επόμενο ραντεβού</div></th>
  </tr>
  
  <?php
   $result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM meeting WHERE pa_id='".$id."' ORDER BY meet_id DESC LIMIT 1" );
$result4 = mysql_fetch_array($result3);{

 ?>
  
  <tr>
 
    <td width="20%">Ημερομηνία:</td>
 
 
  <td><?php  $phpdate2 = $result4['next_date'] ;

 if(($result4['next_date'])=='0000-00-00')
 {
       $mysqldate3 ='Δεν έχει καθοριστεί επόμενο ραντεβού';
    echo $mysqldate3;
 }
 else 
 {
 $mysqldate3 = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($result4['next_date']));
 echo $mysqldate3;
 }

?>

</td>
  
 </tr> 
 
 </tr> 
   <tr>
    <td width="20%">Τοποθεσία :</td>
    <td>
 <?php 
 $company_query8= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mplace WHERE mp_id='".$result4['mp3_id']."'");
 $company8 = mysql_fetch_array($company_query8);
 echo $company8['mp_name'];?></td>
  </tr>
 
 
 
 
 <?php } ?>
 
 
</table>
</div>
   <?php } ?>
  
  

  
  
  
  
  
  
  
<p></p>
<p></p> 
   
   
   
   

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

so i want to reload after the "Επιλέξτε Ασθενή:"

help please

Comment: Way too much code here -- I don't think I can help answer the question without spending several hours trying to understand the code first, which I don't have. If you want an answer here, you need to break the question down into a smaller problem that requires less code. But the state of your code may make that difficult. You might benefit from a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and fix up some of the other problems that make it difficult to work with first.